# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView indexPathForCell:]

Tags: datepicker, ios7, uitableview

OK, I have a problem with to upgrade from iOS 6 to 7.  iOS 6 works fine but I get the following error in iOS7

I am not sure but I think the error occurs here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Events Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = event.name;
return cell;
}
```

Basically when I call a TableViewCell, it brings up a Datepicker but when I hit the "Done" button it crashes.  Any clues?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc133070'



2013-09-24 17:26:14.056 CRM4Life[36587:a0b] -[UITableViewWrapperView indexPathForCell:]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc133070
2013-09-24 17:26:14.097 CRM4Life[36587:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView     indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc133070'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02d425e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019818b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02ddf903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02d3290b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x02d324ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   CRM4Life                            0x0000dd0e -[CoreDataTableViewCell resignFirstResponder] + 206
6   UIKit                               0x00640550 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 347
7   UIKit                               0x00543d0b -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
8   UIKit                               0x00bc30e3 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
9   UIKit                               0x00868651 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 135
10  UIKit                               0x0086aba2 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2640
11  UIKit                               0x0085ef8c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
12  UIKit                               0x0085dc00 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
13  UIKit                               0x0085f66d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
14  UIKit                               0x00862bcd ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
15  UIKit                               0x00862b4e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
16  UIKit                               0x00859248 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
17  UIKit                               0x00525d4a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
18  UIKit                               0x00526c6a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
19  UIKit                               0x004faa36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
20  UIKit                               0x004e4d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
21  CoreFoundation                      0x02ccb8af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
22  CoreFoundation                      0x02ccb23b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
23  CoreFoundation                      0x02ce830e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
24  CoreFoundation                      0x02ce7b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
25  CoreFoundation                      0x02ce794b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
26  GraphicsServices                    0x02f9c9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
27  GraphicsServices                    0x02f9c7fe GSEventRun + 104
28  UIKit                               0x004e794b UIApplicationMain + 1225
29  CRM4Life                            0x0000216d main + 141
30  CRM4Life                            0x000020d5 start + 53
31  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 28):

```
//for iOS 6 or earlier

UITableView* tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;

// for iOS 7 UITableViewWrapperView has been added as superview

if (IOS_7) {
    tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;
}
```

**In iOS7**

*`UITableViewCellScrollView`* has been introduced as subviews of cell &

*`UITableViewWrapperView`* has been introduced as superviews of cell. (Just 1 level extra)

> So if you want to get the UITableView instance out of
>   UITableViewWrapperView, you will have to use superview on
>   UITableViewWrapperView instance.

Comment: @Scubadivingfool Tell me what is your doubt?

Comment: I am not certain what to add for the second superview.

Comment: @Scubadivingfool What you want to add to the second superview?

Comment: Not a clue.  I need the 'done' button on the Datepicker to close but it just freezes and I am not sure how to fix it.  everything works fine in iOS6

Comment: Bad programming practice: never make assumptions about the super view hierarchy from a child view, the dependency graph should only go down not up. You should use a delegate pattern or something similar instead.